# How are default limits and requests values applied if more then one limitrange resource is created in a namespace in a K8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

For example , is the min of all limitranges makes up the overall min for a container. What about the default request then? If more than one default requests are there because there are more than one limitrange resource, which one is picked?

Answer (score 0):

Container resource requests​/limits will overwrite the default namespace requests/limits.

If your container requests/limits do not match the namespace min and max settings your pod will not be scheduled.